# How do I capture a group that matched a pattern using spring and concatenate the matched pattern to another string?

Tags: java, regex, spring

There can be strings like sshexclude1 sshexclude2, I want to capture just the "1" and "2" i.e. the number that follows sshexclude and save it as ssh*, how do I extract that value. This is what I have tried so far .. (i want to save the concatenated value in a bean of type string)

```
<bean id="sshExcludeValue" class="java.util.regex.Pattern" factory-method="compile">
     <constructor-arg value="^sshexclude\d$" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with Spring, but you can just do a simple string regular expression replace, for example:

```
String result = "sshexclude1".replaceFirst("exclude", "");
```

Will give you "ssh1"

Answer (score 0):

[Capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) are used to capture sections of `Strings` in regular expressions. Their application is no different in application context files than in Java code:

```
<bean id="sshExcludeValue" class="java.util.regex.Pattern" factory-method="compile">
   <constructor-arg value="sshexclude(\d+)" />
</bean>
```

`Autowire` a bean to receive the `Pattern`

```
@Autowired
Pattern pattern;
```

and then use `Matcher#matches` to extract the digit(s)

```
String str = "sshexclude2";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.matches()) {
   String newString = "ssh" + matcher.group(1);
}
```

Notice the start and end of line anchors are dropped as [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) matches the complete `String`.